# Can I set CSS to put a whole <p> on a single page (generated content in SalesForce)?

Tags: html, css, salesforce, visualforce, user-generated-content

I'm working in SalesForce. I have a page that generates a PDF based on user specified paramaters. The trouble is that most sometimes the `<p>` run between pages and it looks terrible.

Is there a way (using CSS or HTML) to force a page break if the `<p>` will run between pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page-break = `<div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>`

Not breakable area = `<div style="page-break-inside:avoid">  Not breakable html area </div>`